# libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available

Tags: openssl, cmake, anaconda

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. While using CMake, I got this error:

```
$ cmake --version
cmake: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4)
cmake: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4)
cmake: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/libcurl.so.4)
cmake version 3.5.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

This is what `ldd` returns for OpenSSL:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/openssl
/usr/bin/openssl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
/usr/bin/openssl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
/usr/bin/openssl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd59249000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f5bf2eb5000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f5bf2a71000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5bf26a7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/./libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5bf24a3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5bf312e000)
```

And the version of OpenSSL I installed is `OpenSSL 1.0.2p`. `openssl version` returns `OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018`. To be specific,

```
$ apt-cache policy openssl
openssl:
  Installed: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13
  Candidate: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13 500
    500 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4 500
    500 http://hk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

$ type openssl
openssl is hashed (/home/ddeng/anaconda3/bin/openssl)
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: How did you install OpenSSL? Ubuntu 16.04 contains [openssl 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/openssl) (`openssl version` returns `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`). Please [edit] your question to include the output of the `apt-cache policy openssl` command.

Comment: @Melebius, yes, the question has been updated.

Comment: The version installed by APT is the same as in my case but there seems to be another version in your machine. Please add the output of `type openssl` to your question. BTW, repositories for Precise (12.04) should not be shown in Xenial (16.04), you should review your list of sources.

Comment: @Melebius, I check my /etc/apt/sources.list and comment certain lines. There should be no repositories for Precise anymore.

Comment: Thanks, it looks better without the Precise lines. However, your system seems to prefer OpenSSL from Anaconda instead of the APT version. Unfortunately, I’m not experienced with Anaconda but someone else might know…